# how to get the 'guid's nodeValue in my code using google ajax feed api

Tags: jquery, xml, rss, nodevalue

this is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google AJAX Feed API - Simple Example</title>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("feeds", "1");
    function initialize() {
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=zh-CN&vps=1&jsv=259e&msa=0&output=georss&msid=109685068115364659392.00048b5b630141d82b83a");

      feed.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT);
      feed.load(function(result) {
          if (!result.error) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
              var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
             var guid=entry.xmlNode.getElementsByTagName("id") || entry.xmlNode.getElementsByTagName("guid") ||0
            //console.log($('id',entry.xmlNode.xmlDocument)||$('guid',entry.xmlNode.xmlDocument))
            console.log(guid)
            }
          }
        });
  }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="feed"></div>
  </body>
```

and my code did not get nothing ,

i use jquery's method text() or html() ,but not too ,

so what can i do  .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(entry.xmlNode).find('guid').text()
```

or

```
$('guid', entry.xmlNode).text()
```

But, you cannot do:

```
$(something) || $(somethingElse)
```

because, the code will never get to `$(somethingElse)`, since `$(something)` will return a jQuery object even if no match is found. An object (even an empty jQuery object) is [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/01/javascript-truthy-falsy/), thus the expression is going to be true no matter what the value of `$(somethingElse)`, JavaScript skips evaluating it altogether. It's called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If you do want to find first by `"id"`, then by `"guid"`, then try:

```
var xml = entry.xmlNode;
var guid = $('id', xml).text() || $('guid', xml).text() || 0;
console.log(guid);
```

The reason this works is because we are trying to get a string in each step of the expression, and not an object. An empty string is falsy in JavaScript, hence expressions like:

```
"" || 42; // 42
"" || (40 + 2); // 42
```

will return the second expression (42) as the result.